# Ошибка путей TPath.Combine в Delphi

Tags: android, delphi, пути, delphi-10-berlin

Версия Delphi 10.1
Платформа Android

При указании пути в формате

```
TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDocumentsPath, 'list.s3db');
```

В структуре  проекта появляются ошибки:

```
'TPath' does not contain a member named 'Combine'
'TPath' does not contain a member named 'GetDocumentsPath'
```

При попытке скомпилировать вылетают ошибки

```
E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'Combine'
E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'GetDocumentsPath'
```

И самое интересное, ошибки появляются только после добавления на форму компонента **Timage**, а после его удаления никуда не пропадают, и без него никак.

Предполагаю, что где-то каких-то прав доступа нет или чего-то подобного, но это не точно.

Comment: извиняюсь ) тут у вас дельфи хаха я думал джава хаха

Comment: @Flippy метки под вопросом намекают )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 'TPath' does not contain a member named 'Combine'

Означает, что в классе `TPath` нету метода `Combine`.

Сделайте Ctrl+клик на `TPath` и посмотрите в каком модуле он у вас объявлен (подсказка, правильный модуль должен быть `System.IOUtils`). Есть подозрение, что у вас используется другой класс `TPath` без этих методов.

Что делать?

Вариант 1. Расположить юнит с нужным классом первым в очереди `uses`

Вариант 2. Использовать полный путь класса `IOUtils.TPath.Combine`

Comment: на самом деле классов TPath - два, и они оба в какой-то мере правильные :) Один - визуальный (из FMX.Objects), а второй действительно из IOUtils. Разработчики FMX слегка не состыковались с разработчиками RTL и получили дублирование имен классов...

Comment: Если ещё кто-то столкнётся с этой проблемой и будет тупить так же как и я, вот правильный код  system.iOUtils.TPath.Combine(system.iOUtils.TPath.GetDocumentsPath,

Comment: @ПавелЗайцев если вы *не* используете визуальный класс TPath, вполне достаточно будет расположить модуль `System.IOUtils` в uses секции `implementation`. Ну или в интерфейсной секции, но обязательно *ниже* чем `FMX.Objects`. Тогда для TPath (который из состава IOUtils) можно будет обойтись без упоминания модуля и писать как обычно, не "раздувая" код лишними префиксами.